# Get links from summary section of wikipedia page

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

I am trying to extract links from the summary section of a wikipedia page. I tried the below methods :

This url extracts all the links of the `Deep learning` page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Deep%20learning

And for extracting links associated to any section I can filter based on the section id - for e.g.,

for the `Definition` section of same page I can use this url : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=links&page=Deep%20learning&section=1

for the `Overview` section of same page I can use this url : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=links&page=Deep%20learning&section=2

But I am unable to figure out how to extract only the links from `summary` section

[image]

I even tried using pywikibot to extract linkedpages and adjusting `plnamespace` variable but couldn't get links only for summary section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=links&page=Deep%20learning&section=0

Note that this also includes links in the
{{machine learning bar}} and {{Artificial intelligence|Approaches}} templates however (to the right of the screen).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Pywikibot** with the following commands

```
>>> import pywikibot
>>> from pwikibot import textlib
>>> site = pywikibot.Site('wikipedia:en')  # create a Site object
>>> page = pywikibot.Page(site, 'Deep learning')  # create a Page object
>>> sect = textlib.extract_sections(page.text, site)  # divide content into sections
>>> links = sorted(link.group('title') for link in pywikibot.link_regex.finditer(sect.head))
```

Now `links` is a list containing all link titles in alphabethical order. If you prefer `Page` objects as result you may create them with

```
>>> pages = [pywikibot.Page(site, title) for title in links]
```

It's up to you to create a script with this code snippets.